# How to make sql between a period of time?

Tags: mysql

My database record is partly shown below, i want to use a sql to get records between a period of time in each day.
Such as i want get `01:00 - 03:00` in below records, i expect to get `2004/8/7 01:54`, `2004/8/11 02:41`, how should i do? Thanks:)

```
2004/8/7 01:54
2004/8/7 16:44
2004/8/7 22:26
2004/8/9 16:26
2004/8/9 16:26
2004/8/9 18:36
2004/8/9 18:36
2004/8/9 18:36
2004/8/9 18:36
2004/8/10 23:22
2004/8/10 23:23
2004/8/11 02:41
2004/8/12 21:05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`HOUR()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) function gives you the hour of day. The rest is easy:

```
select * from mytable
where (hour(datetime_column) between 1 and 2
  or (hour(datetime_column) = 3 
    and minute(datetime_column) = 0
    and second(datetime_column) = 0))
```

#### Edited:

Note that `hour(datetime_column) between 1 and 2` matches `... 01:00:00` to `... 02:59:59` and the rest matches the one other second remaining - exactly `03:00:00`.

Comment: Does `between 1 and 3` also return a date like `2012-02-01 1:00`

Comment: Yes, between is the same as <= and >=

Comment: Yes, but note the edit and the explanation. It would have been simpler to match up to *but not including* `03:00:00`

Answer (score 1):

You can use MySQL `HOUR()`:

MySQL `HOUR()` returns the hour of a time. The return value is within the range of 0 to 23 for time-of-day values. The range of time values may be larger than 23.

```
SELECT * 
FROM your_table 
WHERE HOUR(your_date_field) > 1 AND HOUR(your_date_field) < 3
```

Comment: Or if you want the records that *include* hours 1 and 3 you can use hour(fieldname) >= 1 and hour(fieldname) <= 3.